# Not able to add new attribute for an existing API -Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to consume the API in the react app which uses server.js(fakeApi) which generates access tokens,as of now it generated only email, password,exp,someid, I need to include the 'role property

the role can be something admin, manager, user

after decoding

```
 email: "test@gmail.com"
 exp: 1680113994
 iat: 1680110394
 password: "123456"
```

here is my sample json

```
{
"users": [
{ "id": 1, "email": "test@gmail.com", "password": "123456", "role":"Manager"},
{ "id": 2, "email": "test1@gmail.com", "password": "123", "role":"user" }
]
}
```

I am not able to get a role in the access tokens after adding role attribute

server.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const server = jsonServer.create();
const userdb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./users.json", "utf-8"));

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(jsonServer.defaults());

const SECRET_KEY = "72676376";

const expiresIn = "1h";

function createToken(payload) {
return jwt.sign(payload, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn });
}


function isLoginAuthenticated({ email, password, role }) {
 return (
userdb.users.findIndex(
  (user) => user.email === email && user.password === password
) !== -1
);
}

function isRegisterAuthenticated({ email }) {
return userdb.users.findIndex((user) => user.email === email) !== -1;
}

server.post("/api/auth/register", (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;
if (isRegisterAuthenticated({ email })) {
const status = 401;
const message = "Email already exist";
res.status(status).json({ status, message });
return;
}

fs.readFile("./users.json", (err, data) => {
if (err) {
  const status = 401;
  const message = err;
  res.status(status).json({ status, message });
  return;
 }
 data = JSON.parse(data.toString());

 let last_item_id = data.users[data.users.length - 1].id;

 data.users.push({ id: last_item_id + 1, email: email, password: password });
 let writeData = fs.writeFile(
  "./users.json",
  JSON.stringify(data),
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      const status = 401;
      const message = err;
      res.status(status).json({ status, message });
      return;
    }
   }
  );
 });
 const access_token = createToken({ email, password });
 res.status(200).json({ access_token });
 });

server.post("/api/auth/login", (req, res) => {
const { email, password, role } = req.body;

if (!isLoginAuthenticated({ email, password, role })) {
const status = 401;
const message = "Incorrect Email or Password";
res.status(status).json({ status, message });
return;
}

const access_token = createToken({ email, password, role });
res.status(200).json({ access_token });
});


server.listen(5000, () => {
console.log("Running fake api json server");
});
```

Not sure why its not working need some help.Thanks

I have added the roles

```
 server.post("/api/auth/login", (req, res) => {
 const { email, password, **role **} = req.

if (!isLoginAuthenticated({ email, password, **role **})) {
const status = 401;
const message = "Incorrect Email or Password";
res.status(status).json({ status, message });
return;
}
```

My Expectation is need to get the role in the access token